# Where to put the interfaces?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, inversion-of-control, cdi

I have a project that I have an EJB and a WAR, we have a team to work only with the war and other to implement the ejb, I have interfaces to ejb implementation, but now we need to use only the interfaces with stub classes to develop the war layer, you put the interfaces in the war or create other java project to put this interfaces?

```
- business.ejb
- interfaces.jar
- site.war
```

What do you think about this? This 3 projects inside an EAR, but for now, only site.war and interfaces.jar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven for dependency management you can simplify the process and avoid manually creating the interfaces.jar / project by making use of Maven's EJB plugin to generate a client JAR for you:

Generate the client jar: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/generating-ejb-client.html

Use the client jar: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/ejb-client-dependency.html